# DocuSign API C# throwing unable to connect to remote server app for .net framework 4.7 webapi

Tags: docusignapi

When requesting for JWT token from Docusign getting exception with unable to connect to remote server.

"Error when requesting to server"

This issue is coming for .net framework 4.7.2 webapi project but when trying to request the JWT token from .net core 3.1 webapp it is successful.

Is there any setting need to do for .net framework web app project?

Comment: can you share your code? the JWT code should not be different for .NET Core/Framework

Comment: Yes the code to interact with DocuSign API was under .net standard library and when consuming that library to interact with API I am getting error error from .net framework but interacting the DocuSign API with same .net standard library from .net core 3.1 doesn't thrown any error. One more thing I tried to make a API connection to DocuSign directly from .net framework webapi controller but no luck.

Comment: We will need to see your code to try to help.
The SDK support both .NET core and .NET framework, our code examples (via quickstart) are only for .NET Core, but it's possible to use .NET Framework

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see some code that uses .NET framework and not .NET core - https://github.com/docusign/code-example-net-framework-auth-code-grant has it. This code is using Auth Code Grant, not JWT, because that's different for .NET Core vs. MVC with .NET Framework.
The code to get JWT token is the same for .NET core and .NET Framework.
This is the code:

```
    this._authToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
        this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:ClientId"],
        this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:ImpersonatedUserId"],
        this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:AuthServer"],
        DSHelper.ReadFileContent(DSHelper.PrepareFullPrivateKeyFilePath(this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:PrivateKeyFile"])), 1, scopes);
    _account = GetAccountInfo(_authToken);
```

Last suggestion, try the [DocuSign VS Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension). It also supports both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

You can find the C# code in GitHub - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Common/JWTAuth.cs

Comment: public void GetAccessToken()
        {
            var apiClient = new ApiClient();
            var authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken("{{ClientID}}", "{{IpersonateUserID}}", "account-d.docusign.com", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PrivateKey()), 2, new List<string> { "signature", "impersonation" });
        }
        string PrivateKey()
        {
            return File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Downloads\Private.Key");
      }

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body:

Comment: how do you pass the RSA key?  I wonder if you try to put it in XML file? or do you read it from a text file?

Comment: KEY File (.Key) that is the type of file. I do really wonder the same key file is working for .net core api project and not working for .net framework api project. If the key file text is not provided properly have faced the some error as "Invalid key format".

Comment: how did you create the .Key file?

Comment: I have created the text file with the private key from DocuSign APP and while saving changed it to .KEY file format.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the private key as reading the key from file is working with .net core .

Comment: If possible can you try to create a new webapi project with .net framework 4.7.2 then connecting to DocuSign will result out an error.

Comment: I created a console app and used JWT, let me confirm the exact version I used

Comment: Yup, works with 4.7.2, the code that I'm using is on GitHub, let me find the link

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Common/JWTAuth.cs

Comment: The above link have seen and if i try it in the same way got "Unexpected PEM" error but the project you have used is in .net core 3.1 see the below https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/launcher-csharp.csproj

Comment: Try to copy/paste the key into the app.config file. The error you mention is a bad key format.

Comment: This C# code is framework-agnostic, it can work in either .NET Core or .NET Framework. I just tried it with 4.7.2 and it worked.

Comment: Hello

When i run the code locally its working fine but when i run it from the server I'm getting an error - DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Error with response Body: at DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(String clientId, String userId, String oauthBasePath, Byte[] privateKeyBytes, Int32 expiresInHours, List`1 scopes)

Comment: Is all the configuration information the same on your server? the userId? integration Key (clientID)? RSA private key? the URLs you use to make the calls?

Comment: Yes all the configurations were same on local host and on IIS windows host.

Comment: Well, that's as far as I can help as someone will have to go and debug your server. You will need to open a support ticket and take it from there.